# Sulu cms show snippets to particular webspace only

Tags: symfony, sulu

In sulu cms I have multiple web spaces (Means multi domain website, I am managing from single admin panel).

So multi domain website.

For each website I have different user login.

So one user should not see all snippets. User can create snippet webspace (per domain) wise.

For media:
Same user can only see media of his web space only. He should not see media of other webspace. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sulu does currently not support any advanced permission management on the website. The permissions you set in the Administration UI are only taken into account for the Administration UI. You can easily built a login on the website on your own or try to use our [SuluCommunityBundle](https://github.com/sulu/SuluCommunityBundle), but you probably have to build the permission on the website on your own.